# boost::bind not working as expected in multi threaded process

Tags: c++, boost, boost-thread, boost-bind

The following function is called by multiple threads simultaneously.

```
handlework(ItemWork &itemWork)
{
    ItemHandler *itemHandler = NULL;
    itemHandler  = new ItemHandler ();
    itemWork.work(boost::protect(boost::bind(&ItemHandler::writer, itemHandler,  _1,  _2, _3)));
.
.
.
}
```

When they are executed simultaneously by multiple threads, itemHandler object that is created by latest thread is used by the other previously started(still running) threads.

How to avoid that? I mean that each thread when executing the bound function should use its own object.

Let me know if you need more information.

Thanks,
Naga

Comment: are you saving the itemHandler in the itemWork object and calling it from there? in that case previous assignments will be overwritten. if you instead use the itemHandler in the function, .work, it should use the thread-specific one. anyway, the contents of itemwork.work would be useful information.

Comment: thanks. itemHandler is not member variable in itemWork. But the parameters passed to create itemHandler object are member variables of itemWork. Is it a problem?

Comment: What signature of `ItemHandler::writer`?

Comment: Please make it a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) (it _is_ a problem unless you have per-task instances of `itemWork`)

Comment: uint64_t
    ItemHandler::writer(uint8_t* buffer, uint64_t bufferSize, uint64_t offset)
{
    uint64_t returnBufferSize = 0;
    m_offsets.push_back(offset);

    try
    {
          if(m_disk) -->this m_disk is a member variable of ItemWork.
         
           openDisk();  --->fails because it is opening other thread disk
          .
          .
         .
     }

}

Comment: itemWork objects are created by individual threads.

Comment: Assuming your itemWork::work is reentrant you could run it through the debugger with 2 threads to see if it happens consistently when the second thread invokes handleWork. If all these vars are allocated on a per-thread basis the symptom you are describing sounds like non-reentrant code somewhere else (somewhere we're not seeing here)...

Comment: will boost::sharedptr cause this problem? Here itemWork object is shareptr?